# Does AWX 17.0.1 support fetching collections from Github using requirements.yml

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

We are currently using AWX 17.0.1 with Ansible 2.9.17. Does this version of AWX support installing collections directory from a Git repository for example from GitHub? Using `requirements.yml` file?

For example I can get collection **community.mysql** with a file `collections/requirements.yml` from Galaxy as follows:

```yaml
collections:
  - name: community.mysql
    version: '2.1.0'
```

But does AWX also support fetching the collection from Git for example with something similar to below?

```yaml
collections:
  - src: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.mysql.git
    scm: git
    name: community.mysql
    version: master
```

How does this work? Is there any documentation?